# Loading site with getElementById into a div not taking 100% of width

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I'm building a site with bootstrap and I'm loading another site inside my page with javascript:

```
<div id ="content"></div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="1.html" ></object>';
}
<script>
```

it's working just like I want to except the content is not taking 100% of the div, I thought I could fix it with css but it does nothing:

```
#content{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%; /*it changes the size of the div but not the content*/
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here's a pic of what's happening, in the original 1.html the panels take 100% of the document.
[image]

Comment: They're two  panels made with bootstrap, adding "content{100%}" to css did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add this in your css

```
#content object{
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id ="content"></div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object     type="text/html" id="obj" data="1.html" ></object>';
}
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById("obj").style.width = "100%";
}
</script>
```